# how to add a pop up menu in the nav menu in the header of my template in Elementor pro

Tags: elementor

I am new to Elementor only 3 months now, but am building a online store and I am not a web developer.

I am wondering if someone might be able to help me figure out how to create a popup main nav menu system for each product / menu item ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! StackOverflow is a site for programmers to ask about specific programming problems. As far as I can tell, your question is not about programming and is therefore not [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for the site. You might have better luck on a [different stackexchange site](https://stackexchange.com/sites).

Comment: I am very sorry,  I will check out your suggestion and thank you ricky !

Answer (score 1):

1. Open Templates -> popup
2. Create popup structure , add css class name , setup display settings/trigger
3. Under appearance -> menu , setup the CSS name.